# Query activity calculate day difference

Tags: marketing-cloud

Unable to locate the error while using query activity in Marketing Cloud.

```
Select C.Email, P.ISBN__c,  P.TransDate__c,  P.SubscrpEndDate__c P.PubName__c,

DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(), P.SubscrpEndDate__c) AS P.SubscriptionDueDate, 

DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),P.TransDate__c) AS P.TransactionDueDate, 

A.AcctID__c From PrintPurchaseHistoryDE P
Join AccountDE A ON A.AcctId__c = P.AcctID__c
Join ContactDENew C ON C.AcctID__c = A.Acctid__c
```

Throws the following error Incorrect syntax near '.' If i remove the datediff codes it runs fine. Any suggestion to remove the error.

Answer (score 1):

The DateDiff function use looks fine. The problem appears to be in the column aliases being used example:

DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(), P.SubscrpEndDate__c)  **AS P.SubscriptionDueDate**

If you need the column name to have a period in it, then it needs to have single quotes around it.

DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(), P.SubscrpEndDate__c)  AS 'P.SubscriptionDueDate'

Comment: Thanks it worked. However if i add the where condition it throws the  error 'Error while parsing the query please check the syntax. Final code            Select DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(), P.SubscrpEndDate__c)  AS 'P.SubscriptionDueDate', DATEDIFF(day,GETDATE(),P.TransDate__c) AS 'P.TransactionDueDate', A.AcctID__c From PrintPurchaseHistoryDE P
Join AccountDE A ON A.AcctId__c = P.AcctID__c
Join ContactDENew C ON C.AcctID__c = A.Acctid__c
Where P.PubName__c = (Select distinct PubName__c name from P) AND P.SubscrpEndDate__c = Max(P.SubscrpEndDate__c)

Comment: The first where statement:  P.PubName__c = (Select distinct PubName__c name from P), I believe you will need to use the full name "PrintPurchaseHistoryDE", not the alias "P" .   The second statment: P.SubscrpEndDate__c = Max(P.SubscrpEndDate__c), I believe this needs to be a subselect:  P.SubscrpEndDate__c = (select Max(SubscrpEndDate__c) from PrintPurchaseHistoryDE)